# Symfony 4 - Twig - Forms - Send a FORM with GET method adds brackets in URL and include the submit button as parameter

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have two issues when sending a form with the GET method with Symfony 4. This form contains filters and submitting this form updates the list of displayed items according to the selected filters.

The form is built like this:

```php
class MyForm extends AbstractType {

...

    public function buildForm(...) { 

        $builder
            ->setMethod("GET")
            ->add(
                "first_filter",
                ChoiceType::class,
                ...
            )
            ->add(
                "second_filter",
                EntityType::class,
                ...
            )
            ->add(
                "button_apply",
                SubmitType::class
            );
```

First problem, after sending the form, the URL looks like this:

```
/action?my_form[first_filter]=...&my_form[second_filter]=...
```

Is it normal that the form name is included before every field name, and why the URL could not simply be:

```
/action?first_filter=...&second_filter=...
```

The second problem is that the submit button is part of the params visible into the URL:

```
/action?my_form[button_apply]=&...
```

As far as I know, the submit button itself should not be a parameter ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of the Symfony Form component.  Yes, the form name is always posted.  This is to allow handling nested forms.  Yes the submit button is considered to be an html input element since it is possible for one form to have more than one submit buttons.  Hiding all this ugliness is one reason for using POST.  You could work around this by using POST, gathering up the posted information and then redirecting to a GET url.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the full explanation! I guess I will keep the GET, the only thing I wanted to be sure is that it is a "normal" behavior and it does not happen because something is wrong in the way I build and send the form.

Comment: not *quite* right, @Cerad, it's the *default* behaviour. see my answer for details on how to change both ;o)

Answer (score 0):

it's the normal behaviour, and it can be circumvented, but it requires to call `createNamed` instead of `create` on a form factory (see [ControllerTrait::createForm](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5d94ace5ea4d51d64db2840306db0d6a566e55cd/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php#L321)) ... so [Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory::createNamed()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5d94ace5ea4d51d64db2840306db0d6a566e55cd/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php#L36))

```
// at the top: use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory

public function yourControllerAction(FormFactory $formFactory, Request $request) {
    $form = $formFactory->createNamed(
        '',                    // form name, otherwise form class name camel_cased
        YourFormType::class,   // your form type
        [],                    // initial data or object or whatever!
        []                     // form options
    );

    // rest of the script is identical, it's still a normal form
}
```

or you don't inject it and do what the trait does:

```
$form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createNamed(
      // parameters same as before
);
```

for the button to disappear from the GET/POST, I would advise you to remove the button from your form and instead add it to your template (also increases reusability).

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
<button type="submit">{{ 'your label'|trans }}</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

which makes the button submit the form, but since it has no name and value it won't add to the data (in contrast to the `SubmitType` button form type).